# Ruby on rails helper: display mdash if nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Sorry for my English.

I'm in too many places, displays the values ​​of related objects:

```
= post.category.name
```

And this category may be null (nil in Ruby). In Django have `default` filter, which works expense that any unknown variable becomes None (nil) and we can set the default value.

In Rails, in which case an exception NoMethodError, because we are trying to access the meaning of the category name that does not exist.

I wanted to write a helper that catches the exception and returns `&mdash;` but the `post.category.name` value is calculated before passing it to the helper (in principle, logical).

In general, I would like to make here is the following code:

```
= post.category.nil? ? raw ('-'): post.category.name
```

in a more convenient form, like this

```
= mdash(post.category.name)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this instead of the ternary operator?

```
post.category.try(:name) || raw('-')
```

[Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)